# method that throws exception that calls another method that throws a different exception (java)

Tags: java, exception, dictionary, tree, try-catch

TreeInter is an interface with methods, including maximum(). In MapClass, I am trying to use EmptyTreeClass' maximum() to write maximumKey() which returns largest key in object map. However, the two methods throw two different exceptions. If maximimum() catches an exception, the tree remains unchanged. I'm kind of confused how to write maximumKey() despite knowing that I need to use maximum(). Would I need to catch both exceptions in the method?

```
public class UnemptyTreeClass<Key, Value> implements TreeInter<Key, Value> {
    private Key root;
    private Value value;
    private Tree<Key, Value> left, right;

public Key maximum() throws EmptyTreeException {
        try {
            return right.max();
        } catch (EmptyTreeException e) {
            return root;
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class EmptyTreeClass<Key, Value> implements TreeInter<Key, Value> {
    private static EmptyTree emptytree = new EmptyTree();

    public static EmptyTree getInstance() {
        return emptytree;
    }

public Key maximum() throws EmptyTreeException {
        throw new EmptyTreeException();
    }
```

---

```
public class MapClass<Key, Value> {
    Tree<Key,Value> instance= EmptyTree.getInstance();

public Key maximumKey() throws NoSuchElementException{

if (instance==EmptyTree.getInstance())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        try {
            return instance.maximum();
        } catch (EmptyTreeException e) {
            return root; //error here
        }
```

Comment: Why in class UnemptyTreeClass in method maximum() you catch exp and throw the same exception? Now your program will only use the catch block. It won't throw exp out of method.

Comment: You have to catch all exceptions or throws them "upper". You decide which you throws. You can also aggregate them into one exception. Could you write more specific what you want to do? I want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You've not declared root in MapClass, so the following line won't compile:

```
return root;
```